# grouping in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

While passing arguments to a function, how to group parameters into a single argument? 
example

if my script file "my_script.sh" has a function like

```
    echo_arguments() {
    echo $1
    } 
    echo_arguments $1
```

Now in unix command line, How to specify parameters as a single arguments?

```
    ./my_spcript.sh a b c d        #these "a b c d" must fit in $1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group several words into a single parameter in several ways:

```
./my_spcript.sh 'a b c d'
./my_spcript.sh "a b c d"
./my_spcript.sh a\ b\ c\ d
```

Basically, they all come down to telling the shell to treat the spaces as part of a parameter, rather than separators between parameters. All of the above run the script with $1 set to `a b c d`, and $2, $3, etc unset.

However, when you expand $1 without quotes, like this:

```
echo_arguments $1
```

The shell expands $1 *and then resplits it* treating the spaces as separators between parameters. So while my_spcript.sh gets `a b c d` as a single parameter, echo_arguments gets each letter as a separate parameter.  Usually, the best way to fix this is to put $1 in double-quotes to keep it from being re-split (and prevent some other probably undesirable stray parsing as well):

```
echo_arguments "$1"
```

As a general rule, whenever you substitute a variable, you should wrap it in double-quotes to prevent the sort of problem you're seeing. There are cases when you *want* the additional parsing, so you don't want the double-quotes; but unless you have a specific reason for wanting the shell to do the extra parsing, use double-quotes to save headaches.

For your specific example, another way to "fix" this would be to make echo_arguments echo *all* of its arguments, not just the first:

```
echo_arguments() {
    echo "$@"
}
```

Note that `"$@"` expands to all of the current script/function's arguments, each one treated as a separate argument to the command/function they're being passed to (essentially, they're passed through intact).

Answer (score 1):

Surrounding the argument with quotes will allow spaces in the argument - i.e. `./my_spcript.sh 'a b c d'`. You'll need to do the same again inside your script:

```
# my_script.sh
echo_arguments() {
    echo $1
}
echo_arguments "$1"
```

As mentioned by others, $@ (and $*) provide other ways to refer to all of the command line arguments as a group. See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html for details in Bash, for example.

Comment: i tried this like

        ./my_script.sh echo hi

and my output was just 'echo' in $1

Comment: @NathanPk In that example, you didn't use quotes. He told you to add quotes around your arguments when calling the script.

Comment: I just corrected the shortcoming in my original answer. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fits, but you can try to employ "var args" in bash:

```
echo_arguments() {
 echo ${@:1:4}
}

echo_arguments ${@:1:4}
```

This will expand the first 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want these to be a single argument in the script, then pass them in in quotes (single or double):

```
./my_script.sh 'a b c d'
```

If, instead, you want them to be parsed as separate arguments, but you want to pass all of the arguments to your script to the function within it, you can use `$@` to refer to all of them at once.

```
echo_arguments() {
    echo "$@"
} 
echo_arguments "$@"
```